# Creating my custom view in SQL

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have a table like this:

- `UserName nvarchar(50)` (primary key)
- `FieldId nvarchar(50)` (primary key)
- `AvgScore float`

If I want to create a view that show me "what is Max of AvgScore for each UserName.", it can be created easily as follow:

```
SELECT  
    UserName, MAX(AvgScore) AS MaxAvgScore
FROM
    dbo.tblUsersFields
GROUP BY 
    UserName
```

But I want to certain `FieldId` related to `MaxAvgScore`. I tried it:

```
SELECT  
    UserName, FieldId, MAX(AvgScore) AS MaxAvgScore
FROM    
    dbo.tblUsersFields
GROUP BY 
    UserName
```

But that not working. This cause to error:

> Column 'FieldId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What can I do?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. I.e try `GROUP BY UserName, FieldId`.

Comment: You either have to aggregate the `FieldID` column (sum / avg / max / etc.), or add it to the `group by` clause (`...group by UserName, FieldID`)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. In my table, each `UserName` could have several `FieldId` and if I use `GROUP BY UserName, FieldId`, all of combination of `UserName` and `FieldId` are shown, whereas I want just one row for each `UserName` specifying related `FieldId`.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: SQL Server Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By thanks to @JNevill, I improve his answer as final answer:
(See the @JNevill's answer and related comments.)

```
SELECT  t1.UserName, MIN(DISTINCT t2.FieldId) AS FieldId2, t1.MaxAvgScore
FROM
(SELECT  UserName, MAX(AvgScore) AS MaxAvgScore
 FROM    dbo.tblUsersFields
 GROUP BY UserName) AS t1
 INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsersFields AS t2 ON
 t1.UserName = t2.UserName AND t1.MaxAvgScore = t2.AvgScore
 GROUP BY t1.UserName, t1.MaxAvgScore
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the max(avgscore) for each user:

```
 SELECT username, max(avgscore) as maxavgscore) 
 FROM dbo.tblUserFields
 GROUP BY Username
```

Now we can join this result set back into your `tblUserfields` table to get the `FieldID` that corresponds to this unique `Username, MaxAvgScore` combination using an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.username, t2.FieldID, t1.maxavgscore
FROM
    (
        SELECT username, max(avgscore) as maxavgscore
         FROM dbo.tblUserFields
         GROUP BY Username
    ) t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblUserFields t2 ON
        t1.username = t2.username 
        AND t1.maxavgscore = t2.avgscore
```

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. That's great. But if two score met the MaxScore in the table, this command shows both of them. What can I do for this case?

Comment: Dear @JNevill, If I use `MIN(DISTINCT t2.FieldId) AS FieldId2` instead of `t2.FieldId` and put `GROUP BY t1.UserName, t1.MaxAvgScore` at the end of your code, problem is solved. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all non aggregate function columns in your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT  UserName, FieldId, MAX(AvgScore) AS MaxAvgScore
FROM    dbo.tblUsersFields
GROUP BY UserName, FieldId
```

Comment: Thanks @Dessma. But in my table, each `UserName` could have several `FieldId` and if I use `GROUP BY UserName, FieldId`, all of combination of `UserName` and `FieldId` are shown, whereas I want just one row for each `UserName` specifying related `FieldId`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can only address columns which are part of the GROUP BY statement or as parameter for an agregate function.

Instead of

```
GROUP BY UserName
```

write

```
GROUP BY UserName, FieldId
```

If you have alternatinv FieldIds for the same UserName you will need something like:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.FieldId FROM (
SELECT UserName, MAX(AvgScore) FROM tblUsersFields GROUP BY UserName) t1
LEFT JOIN tblUsersFields t2 ON t2.UserName = t1.UserName
```

This will give you one row per FieldId.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf Watteroth. But this code show all data like `GROUP BY UserName, FieldId`.